# Is there a way to find ATMs in Georgia (the country) which can dispense Euro or US dollars?

Tags: online-resources, georgia-country, atms

Here and there I've seen some ATMs in Georgia (the country) which give a choice of currency rather than just offering Georgian lari (`GEL`) like the majority of ATMs.

In fact I can no longer remember whether the ones I saw offered also Euro (`EUR`) or American dollars (`USD`), only that I've been offered a choice sometimes and always just wanted the local currency.

But now I'm about to make my final withdrawal in the country and as the Turkish visa-on-arrival must be paid in either `EUR` or `USD` I'd like to get some in advance since I'm heading that way soon.

So what I need is a website that tells me where the ATMs that give out either foreign currency are located. I know about ATM locators for Visa or Cirrus, etc. But is there also a resource for ATMs in Georgia with the further details I need?

Comment: Out of pure coincidence, the first ATM I tried here in Borjomi offered me all three currencies! I don't think I'd seen that before. I got the impression it was out of the two foreign ones or I was asking for more than the limit... but it also turned out by complete coincidence that my ATM card has gone missing and I didn't notice until today `\-:`

Comment: Don't have a website for you, but I know for a fact that the few (all?) ATMs on Tbilisi's Leselidze street offer you the choice of Lari, USD and Euro. I was there just a few weeks ago.

Comment: Most if not all Bank of Georgia ATMs (yellow ones) offer USD (not sure about euro)

Comment: Given @Giorgi's comment, http://atm.ge/eng/ could be an answer.

Comment: `atm.ge` looks good - I'll give it a try and will know for sure!

Comment: For what it's worth, Lonely Planet (http://www.lonelyplanet.com/georgia/tbilisi/practical-information/money-costs) says all TBC Bank ATMs dispense USD.

Comment: `atm.ge` only covers one bank - it's good for that - doesn't seem to say which currencies are available at each machine though.

Comment: @hippietrail: I just asked Banked of Georgia about it (you can also ask online at https://contact.bog.ge/client/ in english) and she said that every ATM can dispense USD but none of them can dispense EURO

Answer (score 3):

According to some forums on the Caucuses on [Thorn Tree](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2233570):

> in Tbilisi I know for a fact that TBC Bank and VTB have ATMs
>   dispensing dollars because I use them all the time.

So going with that, we have [VTB's English website](http://en.vtb.ge/), which conveniently has an [ATM locator](http://en.vtb.ge/about/atm/)!

So based on that, it should give a pretty good basis for finding them.

Answer (score 2):

If you withdraw **US dollars**, almost all banks allow their ATMs to withdraw USD (except for VTB bank, which allows it only to their customers).

Very few banks and ATMs allow withdrawing **EUR (€)** with foreign bank cards. There are only 2 banks (as of November 2020): ProCredit and TBC. I have added more detailed info about [withdrawing euro in Georgia](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)#ATMs) to WikiVoyage.